# Best way to load a specific component knowing its selector as variable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I am building a simple game with Angular.

A game can have multiple rounds. Each round can be different from the others, and I use the variable `roundType` to distinguish them.
For example, a round can have `roundType` equals to:

- NORMAL => "Read the question and choose the answer you think is correct"
- SONG => "Listen to the song and choose the answer you think is correct"
- IMAGE => "Look at the image and choose the answer you think is correct"

Each round will have multiple questions/songs/images.

As each round type have different behavior, I created 3 different components with these selectors:

- round-normal
- round-song
- round-image

This way, I can load components on the parent.component.html, like this:

```
<div>
  <round-normal *ngIf="roundType == 'NORMAL'"></round-normal>
  <round-song *ngIf="roundType == 'SONG'"></round-song>
  <round-image *ngIf="roundType == 'IMAGE'"></round-image>
</div>
```

Since I am planning to add more round types in the near future, I can't have 20 rows like that, and I know for sure that this is not the right approach, it just feels wrong and bad coding.

I read the Angular docs, but I did not found any use-case close enough, to choose a solution.
And that's why I'm here to ask you suggestions on what is the best way to proceed.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at [dynamic component loading in angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: Consider routing.

Comment: So, @LukaszGawrys, you are right. Just tested and it works. Now, should I let you write an answer, or do you want me to answer my self and close the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use routing to render each component for example use /normal and /song and /image for each component and you might need a service if you want to store their scores and thats why you need them to be in the same component.